# Picasso Custom Downloader Issue

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, picasso, okhttp

I need to retrieve an image from my api that requires header authentication.  I am specifying a custom downloader for Picasso but the image is never display.  Am I overriding the openConnection method correctly?

```
Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        builder.downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(getApplicationContext()) {
            @Override
            protected HttpURLConnection openConnection(Uri uri) throws IOException {
                HttpURLConnection connection = super.openConnection(uri);
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setRequestProperty("X_AUTH_TOKEN", authToken);

                return connection;
            }
        });
        Picasso picasso = builder.build();
        picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://example.com/api/users/pic/14").into(ivProfilePic);
```

Comment: Try to change to connection.setDoOutput(false);

Comment: @TizianoPiccardi tested and not working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do not use `Picasso.with()`. That's a static method that initializes the default `Picasso` instance.

You are building an instance of yours with the custom downloader but you are not using it.

Just call `picasso.load()` directly after your build your instance.